# Filling second drop-down multiselect with first drop-down in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am new to angular and I am using the angular js-dropdown-multi select module from [**HERE**](http://dotansimha.github.io/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect/docs/#/main).

I am trying to fill the second drop-down based on first drop-down selection, the first issue I am facing here is when I select single item all are getting selected and second when I try to console the selected one I see `[Object object]`, what does that mean?

Any help is much appreciated.

[Plunker Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/dzWCuepCWtBCJvnfFPx7?p=preview)

HTML:

```
<div ng-dropdown-multiselect="" 
     options="example14data" 
     events="eventSettings" 
     selected-model="example14model" 
     extra-settings="example14settings">
</div>

<div ng-dropdown-multiselect="" 
     options="example15data"
     selected-model="example15model" 
     extra-settings="example15settings">
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['angularjs-dropdown-multiselect']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';

  $scope.example14model = [];
    $scope.example14settings = {
        scrollable: true,
        enableSearch: true,
         displayProp: 'type1'
    };

    $scope.eventSettings={
     onItemSelect: function (item) {
       console.log('selected: '+item);
            }
    }

    $scope.example14data = [
      {
        "type1":"A",
        "servers":[
          {
            "type2":"a"
          },
          {
            "type2":"b"
          },
          {
            "type2":"c"
          }
          ]
      },
      {
        "type1":"B",
        "servers":[
          {
            "type2":"d"
          },
          {
            "type2":"e"
          },
          {
            "type2":"f"
          }
          ]
      },
      {
        "type1":"C",
        "servers":[
          {
            "type2":"g"
          },
          {
            "type2":"h"
          },
          {
            "type2":"i"
          }
          ]
      },
      ];


    $scope.example15model = [];
    $scope.example15settings = {
        scrollableHeight: '200px',
        scrollable: true,
        enableSearch: true,
        selectionLimit:1,
         displayProp: 'id'
    };

    $scope.example15data = [];

    $scope.example3settings = {

    };

});
```

Comment: Here is the plunk https://plnkr.co/edit/dzWCuepCWtBCJvnfFPx7?p=preview

Comment: what is this supposed to do, exactly?  right now the first dropdown doesn't even seem to work correctly; i.e. if I select `b`, it causes `a`, `b`, *and* `c` to **all** be checked, even though it only says "1 checked".  checking multiples does not appear possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the idProp setting so that AngularJS Dropdown Multiselect knows what the unique id of the data is:

```
$scope.example14settings = {
    scrollable: true,
    enableSearch: true,
     displayProp: 'type1',
     idProp: 'type1',
};
```

You are concatenating the item variable and a string string which is why you are seeing the `[Object object]`

The following code will display the value of item

```
$scope.eventSettings={
  onItemSelect: function (item) {
     console.log('Selected:');
     console.log(item);
  }
}
```